# android NDK function returning wrong values for 64bits variables (double, long int)

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to cope with android NDK in android studio, I set up a demo app with a jni folder with the required files, it seems to work as expected when I call a function that returns an int or a const char*, but when it comes to doubles it just doesn't behave. 
I tried to cast the returned value to jdouble, and also tried to declare the functions as returning a long double with same results. The app is running on a nexus 5 and I have no idea what's wrong.
As requested, here a few try, on the left the return statement in c, on the right the value got in java
return 0 -> 0
return 1 -> 0
return 1.555 -> -1.374389535E9
return 10 -> 0
return 10.555 -> -1.71798692E8
return 2000 -> 0
return 2000.123 -> -2.0615843E8
Ok, it seems like integer values are returned as 0...?

**EDIT:**
I added a new function getMyLong as done with other functions

```
long int getMyLong(){ return 0x1122334455667788;}
```

the interesting thing is, if in main.c the bridge function is defined calling the function from func.c it returns just what appears to be a 32bit portion, while if I return the value directly from the bridge function, it works and so it does with doubles

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_lelloman_jni_1test_MainActivity_getMyLong
    (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){
          return getMyLong(); // this one will return 1432778632 in java
          //return 0x1122334455667788; this one returns 1234605616436508552 
    }
```

**Edit2**:
regarding the build configuration and ndk, I barely know what I'm doing but I'll do my best to point out what I know:
- in local.properties I added this line `ndk.dir=/usr/share/android-studio/data/ndk`
- in ndk/RELEASE.TXT says `r10c (64-bit)`
- in build.gradle I added this inside defaultConfig (I also tried without cFlags, it's the same)

```
ndk {
    moduleName "ndkTest"
    cFlags "-std=c99"
}
```

- javah generated a file named `com_lelloman_jni_test_MainActivity.h`, the only include there is `#include <jni.h>`
- I wrote main.c and the only include is the file generated with javah


main.c

```
#include "com_lelloman_jni_test_MainActivity.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_lelloman_jni_1test_MainActivity_getMyInt
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint b, jint h){
        return getMyInt( b, h);
  }    
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_lelloman_jni_1test_MainActivity_getMyDouble
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdouble r){
        return getMyDouble(r);
  }
```

func.h

```
#ifndef FUNC_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNC_H_INCLUDED


int getMyInt(int b,int h);
double getMyDouble(double r);
const char* getMyString(int q);

#endif // FUNC_H_INCLUDED
```

func.c

```
#include "func.h"

#ifndef PI
#define PI 3.14159265359
#endif // PI


int getMyInt(int b,int h){
    return b*h;
}

double getMyDouble(double r){
    //return r*PI*2;
    //return 5;
    return 1*2.23;
}
```

Comment: What output is generated by the code above?  (Might be easier to capture if you just wrote the return values to logcat.)

Comment: @fadden I added a few values I've just tried

Comment: Usually with things like this the problem is that you're losing half of the 64-bit value somewhere along the way.  For example, 3 is 0x4008000000000000, while 3.14159265359 is 0x400921fb54442eea.  So it seems like you're losing the high 32 bits.  It's not clear from the code why that would be.  You could try an experiment with jlong and see if you can pass a value like 0x1122334455667788 both directions.

Comment: @fadden thanks, I made a try as you suggested and edited the question accordingly, the plot thickens

Comment: With regard to your jlong test, I expect that fails because you declared your internal function as `long int getMyLong()` which (at least on the 32-bit arm NDK) is a 32-bit type, while a jlong should be a 64-bit type everywhere.  You probably should have declared it as long long, jlong, or int64_t.  It would help if you stated what ndk and ABI you are using.  Also, can you try running on a 4.4 or earlier arm emulator.  Any chance a host header file could be sneaking in in place of an ndk one?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm going to try with long long int and the emulator, however, what do you mean when you say that a host header file could be sneaking in place of an ndk one? Please don't curse me :)

Comment: I mean that you might accidentally be referencing a header file intended for compiling programs to run on your development machine (ie, /usr/include/whatever.h) instead of the comparable file in the ndk distribution intended for programs that run on an Android device.  Often the API of the host machine and the android device has enough gross similarities for some things to still work, but enough subtle differences for others to sneakily fail.  Perhaps of more relevance, you seem to be using a recent 64-bit NDK.  Do you have an older 32-bit (only) one around you could try for comparison?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for your patience, I don't have any other ndk but Im going to download the r10c 32bit version, regarding the sneaking headers I really don't know if and how it could happen, I'm totally new to both android studio and ndk :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Main.c` should include `func.h`, or else `main.c` thinks `getMyDouble()` returns an `int`.